# How to select a option in combo box or drop down in web driver.....?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using a method for seleniumRC `driver.select(selectLocator, Optionvalue)`
How to replace it in selenium web driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webdriver you can use following:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.*locator*("*value*"))).selectByVisibleText("text");
```

Here selectBy also has various methods like selectByIndex, selectByValue.